# SQL Server : rank data based on minimum distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ranking, row-number

I have two tables with cities, like the following:

Table 1

```
Place.1 | Latitude.1 | Longitude.1
```

Table 2

```
Place.2 | Latitude.2 | Longitude.2
```

Many places in the two tables are the same, but I cannot join them based on the `Place` name, since they are in different languages, so I was thinking of joining based on minimum distance.

There is a way to calculate the great circle distance between two points on a sphere (I have already implemented this function). Any ideas how I could find the closest place on Table 2 for every place on Table 1??

Thank you very much for any help!

Alex

Comment: If they are indeed the same place but in different languages, are you able to create a unique key that is the same in both and therefore available to use in a JOIN?

Comment: You can use the `.STDistance()` function on `geography` columns to find the distance between them on MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      order by distance(t1, t2)  -- put your appropriate function here
     ) t2;
```